# How to customize which Windows $PATH environment variables are imported into Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I would like to customize the `$PATH` variables included in the Cygwin environment, how can I do this? One solution I know of is to add the following line to the end of the Cygwin.bat file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

By default the shortcut starts bin/mintty.exe, how can I change that default behavior?

Comment: see the Related questions on the right hand side of this page

Comment: but, did not fix my problem, could u pls explain more/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Windows environment variables are included in your Cygwin environment [automatically](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html) on startup. If you'd like to customize what they are, you can overwrite the whole `$PATH` variable using a line similar to what you already mentioned in your `Cygwin.bat` file:

```
PATH="colon:separated:list:of:all:paths"
```

Also if you'd like to change which terminal is used by Cygwin, one alternative is [rxvt](http://www.arwin.net/tech/cygwin/).

Another popular solution seems to be using PuttyCyg to putty directly into your Cygwin installation to get the benefits of the Putty terminal. See the [effective-cygwin](https://github.com/oseparovic/effective-cygwin) 
GitHub page for setup instructions and more.

See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701895/best-terminal-environment-for-cygwin-windows) for a full list of suggested alternatives to the default Cygwin terminal.